# Animate UITableViewCell moving to bottom programatically

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a set of cells in the same section. When I press a button on one of the cells, I would like it to move to the bottom, with an animation, moving over the other cells. The animation I have in mind is similar to what happens when you drag a cell around in editing mode, but I would like it to be done programmatically when I tap on a button. 
For what I have gathered, I should use `tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath`, but I can't seem to do it properly:

```
 //inside the function for when the button is pressed
 let cell = sender.superview?.superview?.superview as! MainTableViewCell
 let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
 let goal = goals[(indexPath?.row)!]

 goals.removeAtIndex((indexPath?.row)!)
 goals.append(goal)

 tableView.beginUpdates()
 self.tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: indexPaths.last!)
 tableView.endUpdates()

 tableView.reloadData()
```

After this, the function disables the button that triggers the function itself. What I have noticed happening is that not only does the cell that I would like to move get disabled, but the last cell in the section also does. If the last cell is already disabled, then the cell before last gets disabled and so on. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I also call `canMoveRowAtIndexPath` and return true.

Comment: The animation you get from moveRowAtIndexPath doesn't fit your need? or is the animation not working?

Comment: @bbjay animation is not working.

Comment: Regarding this 'weird' button behavior, I would never rely on directly modifying a `UITableViewCell`'s views while simultaneously manipulating table rows, especially when followed by `reloadData`. Whether or not to enable the button should be a piece of information kept as part of your model and used to configure the cell appropriately in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `tableView.reloadData()` your will lose you animation effect. You should just be able to move the cell, then update your data source (the `goals` array) to reflect the new order of the items. You also do not need to call `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` for a single update. You would use those calls to batch multiple updates (inserts, deletes, moves, etc.)

```
//inside the function for when the button is pressed
 let cell = sender.superview?.superview?.superview as! MainTableViewCell
 let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
 let goal = goals[(indexPath?.row)!]

 tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: indexPaths.last!)
 goals.removeAtIndex((indexPath?.row)!)
 goals.append(goal)
```

I created a simple test project to verify, using simple strings as the data items, and the animation effect worked as expected. See gist here: [MoveTableRow](https://gist.github.com/dkw5877/95387a8de2e2bed8e80e9c54effd0673)

Answer (score 1):

I do this so:

```
UIView.transition(with: tableView, duration: 0.35, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: { self.tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: indexPath.last) })
```

For move to the beginning:

```
UIView.transition(with: tableView, duration: 0.35, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: { self.tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: [0,0]) })
```